# C99/C11 Self-referencing Sub-object Initialization possible?

Tags: c, c99, c11, subobject

I should first say I don't think what I want to do is possible (having read what I think are the relevant parts of the ISO C99) but here is rough idea of what I have now:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int *y;
};

#define FOO_INITIALIZER(name) \
{                             \
    .x = 1,                   \
    .y = &(name).x,           \
}

struct foo bar = FOO_INITIALIZER(bar);
```

This works in C99/C11 but what I really want is to drop the name parameter to the FOO_INITIALIZER macro. Is that possible?

I know this doesn't work:

```
#define FOO_INITIALIZER       \
{                             \
    .x = 1,                   \
    .y = &.x,                 \
}
```

If it is possible what section of ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 should I be looking in?

Comment: What about [`struct foo FOO_INITIALIZER(bar);`](https://ideone.com/e1LQjZ)

Comment: Very similar to above though it does have one benefit: not needing to put the name twice. It looks like that is the best that can be done with current C (or future C as I doubt WG14 will add self-referencing to the standard).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve what you want in the standard C language. You can either continue passing a name (but this does not work well for nested objects) or store offsets instead of pointers if this makes sense (highly dependent on the application) via `offsetof`.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for confirming. Figured I would ask stackoverflow before I give up on the macro syntax I was after.